How to get mean/average line of multiple points (with different x-axis values) using R (or Excel)?
I have two dataframes (fire2022_12 and fire2021_12) with the same three columns (variable, x, y). I have pasted a snippet from the top of these dataframes below. I can plot these two dataframes in the same plot just fine, by doing this:
ggplot() + geom_line(data=fire2022_12, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(data=fire2021_12, aes(x, y))
I now want to create a line that represents the mean/average of these two dataframes, so that I can see, on average, how 'time since fire' (x) affects the habitat suitability (y (0-1)) of a species. However, I am having trouble with this. I think what is causing issues is the fact that there isn't a perfect overlap between the x-axis values between both dataframes, so if an x-axis value is only present on one data frame, it adopts that one instead of omitting it (or aligning to rest of the mean/average 'curve').
fire2022_12
timesincefire202212v2,-115.1,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-113.71879999999999,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-112.3376,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-110.9564,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-109.5752,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-108.19399999999999,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-106.8128,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-105.4316,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-104.0504,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-102.66919999999999,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-101.288,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-99.9068,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-98.5256,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-97.14439999999999,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-95.7632,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-94.382,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-93.0008,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-91.61959999999999,0.8304737597703934
timesincefire202212v2,-90.2384,0.8304737597703934

fire2021_12
timesincefire2021_12,-113.9,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-112.53320000000001,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-111.16640000000001,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-109.7996,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-108.4328,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-107.066,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-105.6992,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-104.3324,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-102.96560000000001,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-101.59880000000001,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-100.232,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-98.8652,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-97.4984,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-96.1316,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-94.76480000000001,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-93.398,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-92.0312,0.9661756336688996
timesincefire2021_12,-90.6644,0.9661756336688996

The closest I have come to a desired result is this:
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

#merging two dataframes into one
data2 <- rbind(fire2022_12, fire2021_12)

#rounding the x-axis values to a whole number
data2$x <- round(data2$x, 0)

#obtaining the mean y-axis value for each x-axis value
grouped <- data2 %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(y = mean(y))

#plotting the data 
ggplot(data=grouped, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point()

When I plot the data, it looks like there are 3 lines instead of 1. I think this is happening because for some x-axis values, there is only y-axis value for one of the dataframes and not both. For example, the x-axis value of -115 is only present on fire2022_12 and not on fire2021_12, so when it calculates the mean, it just takes fire2022_12's value. It would be nice if I could omit these outliers somehow, or force them to be aligned to the x-axis values that do have y-axis values across both dataframes.
I have included some screenshots below.
Screenshot 1: My result My result
Screenshot 2: What the original plotted dataframes looked like before I tried to create a 'mean/average' line* Screenshot 2
Screenshot 3: The result I get when I set geom to 'line' instead of 'point' Screenshot 3
Thank you in advance! :)
note: I have also tried using ggplot2's stat_summary() but I run into a similar issue.

Hello @Frek, welcome to SO. Please, check your sample data: all values in fire2022_12$y and fire2021_12$y are repeated.

Assuming you've looked at the data after the rbind step and that it looks right, please share sample data at that point. The nicest way to share sample data is with dput, e.g., dput(data2[1:10, ]) will make copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 10 rows of data2, or dput(data2[c(1:5, 101:105), ]) would share rows 1 to 5 and 101 to 105. Please choose a small subset of your data to share that illustrates the problem - not one where the values are all the same.

My guess is that rounding x isn't a very good grouper. If I assume x is your 2nd column (it would also be nice if you'd included column names so we can be sure), we can see that both data sets have x values that will get rounded to 91, 92, 93, but only the first has a 94 value and only the second has a 95 value. So if a certain x value only occurs in one data set, there's nothing to average. I bet the 3 lines you're seeing are (1) a line in the middle when there is an average, (2) a top line when only in one data set, (3) a bottom line when only the other data set.

You might do better not calculating an average at all, and instead using a GAM or LOESS smoother on the raw data, like geom_smooth().

Rather than rounding, try using a smooth line:
rbind(df1, df2) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_smooth()

Using Andre's nicely shared data, that ends up with this:


Wow this is so nice and simple, thank you so much!! :)

One way to approach this is to get a shared x value between both data sets by using as.integer, then generating the y mean values by row.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

inner_join(df1 %>% 
             mutate(intx = as.integer(x)), 
           df2 %>% 
             mutate(intx = as.integer(x)), "intx") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Mean = mean(c(y.x, y.y))) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_line(aes(intx, Mean, col="Mean"))

Note that inner_join only keeps those x values that are present in both frames. It can be made more fine grained by first dividing x by 10, and then de-duplicating with e.g. make.unique

Data
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", 
"fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", 
"fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", 
"fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12", "fire2022_12"
), x = c(-115.1, -113.71879, -112.3376, -110.9564, -109.5752, 
-108.1939, -106.8128, -105.4316, -104.0504, -102.66919, -101.288, 
-99.9068, -98.5256, -97.14439, -95.7632, -94.382, -93.0008, -91.61959
), y = c(0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 
0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 
0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 
0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 
0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393, 0.830473759770393)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

df2 <- structure(list(name = c("fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", 
"fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", 
"fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", 
"fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12", "fire2021_12"
), x = c(-113.9, -112.5332, -111.1664, -109.7996, -108.4328, 
-107.066, -105.6992, -104.3324, -102.9656, -101.5988, -100.232, 
-98.8652, -97.4984, -96.1316, -94.7648, -93.398, -92.0312, -90.6644
), y = c(0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 
0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 
0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 
0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689, 
0.9661756336689, 0.9661756336689)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))


Thank you so much Andre, this is super helpful!! I ended up accepting Gregor's answer since it's simpler and does not seem to omit data, but I'll definitely keep your tips in mind. :)
